# error autoloading failed to define function when loading custom file

Tags: init-file, use-package

I recently decided rewrite my [emacs configuration](https://github.com/andreanicastro/emacs_config). I want to load my custom org configuration only in the case when I am opening a *.org file. Considering a minimalistic configuration of init.el

```
(use-package orgmode-setup
  :load-path "custom/"
  :mode "\\.org\\'"
  )
```

that loads a orgmode-setup.el in .emacs.d/custom that looks like this

```
(provide 'orgmode-setup)
```

however I get the error

> File mode specification error: (error Autoloading failed to define
>   function orgmode-setup)

However, before I am doing the same thing with Ido

```
(use-package ido-setup
  :load-path "custom/"
  )
```

with ido-setup.el saved in the  .emacs.d/custom folder.

I am not proficient with emacs, could you please help me to debug this?